# How do I convert every element of a nested list in a dict into an int?

Tags: python, list, csv, dictionary, int

So I have a function that takes a CSV and converts it into a dictionary.

Code:

```
import io

opened_statcsv = io.StringIO('''"ID","HP","Attack","Defense","Speed"
6,78,84,78,100
146,90,100,90,90
643,100,120,100,90
''')

def read_stats_file(filename):
    sdb={}

    #opened_statcsv = open(filename, 'r')
    stat_string = opened_statcsv.readlines()

    for i in range(1,len(stat_string)):
        splitline=stat_string[i].replace("\n",'').split(',')

        sdb[splitline[0]] = splitline[1],splitline[2],splitline[3],splitline[4]
    print(sdb)

read_stats_file('stats_file2.csv')
```

Currently, I can create the dictionary with one issue: Every single number has quotes around it.

For example, my output right now is: {'6': ('78', '84', '78', '100'), '643': ('100', '120', '100', '90')}

When it should be: {6: (78, 84, 78, 100), 643: (100, 120, 100, 90)}

Is there any way to convert all of these values into ints before building the dictionary (since they become immutable tuples after that)?

I am not allowed to import CSV or map and It is recommended to avoid using .strip or .replace.

Comment: try using `int`. And you don't really need `.replace`

Comment: I have, I just don't know where to put it. I tried saying 
"for l in splitline
 l = int(l)" but then it took all the elements of the list and combined it into one big list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As also suggested in a comment try:

```
for i in range(1,len(stat_string)):
    splitline=stat_string[i].replace("\n",'').split(',')

    sdb[int(splitline[0])) = ( int(splitline[1]),int(splitline[2]),int(splitline[3]),int(splitline[4] )
```

Comment: This works for all the values of my dict, but the keys still have quotes around them. How would I fix the without getting a "cannot assign to function call error"?

Comment: @ruckarucka `sdb[int(splitline[0])] = ...`

Comment: Thank you @juanpa.arrivillaga and @Claudio! it worked. I will accept the answer as soon as the time limit goes down.

Answer (score 1):

in this case, i'll suggest [map](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map) function

```
for i in range(1,len(stat_string)):
    splitline=map(int, stat_string[i].replace("\n",'').split(','))

    sdb[splitline[0]] = splitline[1],splitline[2],splitline[3],splitline[4]
```

Comment: You need to use `list(map(...))` in Python 3.

Comment: Unfortunately I am not allowed to use map

Comment: @ruckarucka what *are* you allowed to use, and why all the silly restrictions?

Comment: I am allowed to use only basic python, the restrictions are because this is an intro to python assignment. Believe me, I would have imported csv long ago if I was allowed to.

Comment: int() for every member is ok.